# Bokeh - Slider, RadioGroup callback conflict

Tags: javascript, widget, bokeh, radio-group

Here's is a simplified version of my bokeh:
df

```
YEAR |  AMOUNT   |NAME  |  NEST           |  FUND
2011     10        Joe      ("Q1",Jan")      JPN
2012    -20        Joe      ("Q2","Feb")     CAD
2013     30        Joe      ("Q3", "Apr")    USD
2011     12        Arn      ("Q1",Jan")      USD
2012    -250       Arn      ("Q2","Feb")     JPN
2013    -36        Arn      ("Q3", "Apr")    JPN
```

I have a Stacked Grouped Bar chart showing the amounts for Joe or Arn. Joe or Arn is controlled by a `radio_group`. The stacks are `FUND`. The axis groups is `NEST`

```
factors = [
    ("Q1", "Jan"), ("Q1", "Feb"), ("Q1", "Mar"),
    ("Q2", "Apr"), ("Q2", "May"), ("Q2", "Jun"),
    ("Q3", "Jul"), ("Q3", "Aug"), ("Q3", "Sep"),
    ("Q4", "Oct"), ("Q4", "Nov"), ("Q4", "Dec"),
]

stacks=list(set(df.loc[df['FUND']))

bar_src= ColumnDataSource(data=df)
p= figure(plot_width=1150, plot_height=550, x_range=FactorRange(*factors))
view = CDSView(source=bar_src, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name="Name", group="Joe")])    
p.vbar_stack(stacks, x = "NESTS", width = 0.9 source = bar_src, view=view)

radio_group=RadioGroup(labels=['Joe','Arn'], active=0)
radio_group.callback=CustomJS(args=dict(source = bar_src, filter=view.filters[0]),
code="""filter.group = cb_obj.labels[cb_obj.active]
    source.change.emit();""")
```

I also have a year `Slider`

```
def year_chg(attr,old,new):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'YEAR':df['YEAR'][df['YEAR']==slider.value],
        'NEST':df['NEST'][df['YEAR']==slider.value],
        'NAME':df['ACCT_NUM'][df['YEAR']==slider.value],
        'FUND':df['FUND'][df['YEAR']==slider.value],
        'AMOUNT':df['AMOUNT'][df['YEAR']==slider.value],
        })
    new_data=ColumnDataSource(data=new_df)
    bar_src.data = new_data.data

slider= Slider(start=2011, end=2013.year, step=1, value=2013, title='Year')
slider.on_change('value',year_chg)
```

The interactions all work in isolation. However, when combined together, sliding the slider results in a blank plot with very tiny characters on the upper left.

I've also tried wrapping the radio CustomJS into a python function and then calling `radio_group.js_on_change("active", CustomJS.from_py_func(change_name))` but it yields the same result.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a complete minimal reproducer, it is hard to say anything concrete, However, you should not assign the `.data` from one CDS to another CDS as you are doing in `year_chg`. In the upcoming Bokeh 2.0 trying to do this will raise an explicit error message. Although it behaves similar to a `dict`, it is not. In order to support all the automatic synchronization between Python and JS the CDS `.data` is actually a very specialized data structure that has linkages to many other things, and "re-homing" them from one CDS to another is not supported. You should only ever assign to `.data` from a *plain python dict*

```
source.data = { ... } # plain python dict
```

If you need to adapt a DataFrame there is a `.from_df` method on CDS that will create the appropriate plain python dict structure you can use to assign from.